# Weird Bug - Loading and going back to mapFragment after AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-maps-v2

Im having a really weird problem here. Can't figure out what is going on. In my app I have the following happening:

1. MapFragment is loaded on the FrameLayout of my activity.
2. User click on an InfoWindow of a Marker
3. AlertDialog pops up asking if he is sure to procced
4. If Ok, I load another fragment on the same FrameLayout
5. When user hits the back button to load the map again, the map is bugging. I mean, navigate is really slow and glitchy.

The weird part is that if I don't pop up the AlertDialog it works fine.

The code is:

```
public class MyMapFragment extends Fragment implements LocationListener, GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {
    private GoogleMap map;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        //...

        map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInfoWindowClick(final Marker marker) {

                AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                                        .setTitle("Confirmação")
                                        .setMessage("Essa ação gastará 1 de energia")
                                        .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                            @Override
                                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                                UFVQuestUtils.user.setEnergyLeft(UFVQuestUtils.user.getEnergyLeft() - 1);
                                                parent.navigationDrawerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                                Quest q = UFVQuestUtils.questMarkerMap.get(marker);

                                                if (q != null) {
                                                    final Fragment fragment;
                                                    if (q instanceof GoToAndAnswerQuest) {
                                                        fragment = new GoToAndAnswerFragment();
                                                    } else {
                                                        fragment = new SeekAndAnswerFragment();
                                                    }

                                                    if (fragment != null) {
                                                        UFVQuestUtils.currentQuest = q;
                                                        UFVQuestUtils.currentMarker = marker;
                                                        FragmentTransaction transaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

                                                        transaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
                                                        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                                                        transaction.commit();

                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        })
                                        .setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                            @Override
                                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                                // Do nothing
                                            }
                                        }).create();
                alert.show();
            }
        });
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Try implementing onBackPressed method if you didn't yet, and specifiy there what should happen. It should Override any other methods.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it didn't work and I really dont see why it should. Besides I really need to stack my map fragment, once I want the user to return to the map on the same position he left instead of starting the fragment again. Any other ideas?